# PDO PostgreSQL quoted identifiers in WHERE

Tags: php, postgresql

I am developing a PHP project. I was using MySQL database, but I decided to migrate to Postgres because better optimization(easy work) with Openlayers and Geoserver.
I was using PDO because they promise easy migrate to different database.

I experienced basic problem with WHERE clauses. My code is:

```
$query = Database::$DB->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID=?;');
```

But, I get an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "id" does not
>   exist LINE 1: SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID=$1;

I changed the code to:

```
$query = Database::$DB->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE "ID"=?;');
```

and it works.

When I was learning PDO, I didn't experienced that identifiers would be quoted. My project is big and there will be a lot of work to quoted all identifiers in WHERE clause, but no problem if this is need to be done.

Before I do this, I would like to ask someone, to shine some light on this matter.

Comment: this question has nothing to do with PDO. The latter just sends your query to Postgre as is and returns an error. So - it's probably some Postgre setting

Comment: Just to be clear (I see Milen A. Radev just edited the question), the database is "Postgres" or "PostgreSQL", never "Postgre".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is nothing to do with PDO, but the underlying database. PDO is quite a light wrapper, and doesn't do complex re-mapping of queries to handle differences in the SQL accepted by different flavours of DBMS.

In Postgres, all identifiers such as table and column names are case sensitive, and folded to lower-case on input if not quoted. So `ID` is a different column name to `id`, but `WHERE ID=5` is translated to `WHERE id=5` automatically.

The "encapsulation" in double-quotes is how Postgres quotes identifiers, equivalent to backticks in MySQL or square brackets in MS SQL Server. They preserve case as well as allowing things like spaces, so `WHERE "ID"=5` tells Postgres that you really meant upper-case.

Quoting examples:

```
-- MySQL
SELECT * FROM `table with a space`;

-- PostgreSQL
SELECT * FROM "table with a space";

-- MS SQL Server
SELECT * FROM [table with a space]
```

The easiest solution is just to name all your Postgres tables and columns in lower-case. The downside is that results from queries like `SELECT ID FROM users WHERE ...` will come back with lower-case keys in the results, which may break assumptions further down your PHP code. As a compromise, you can fix your `SELECT` clauses to use the uppercase form as an alias, as in `SELECT id as "ID" FROM users WHERE ...`

Comment: It should be noted that double quotes `""` are the **SQL standard** for quoting identifiers: `"queer NaMe"`. That's what Oracle uses (just like Postgres) and that's also what should be used in MySQL with with `SET sql_mode = 'ANSI';` Only Microsoft thinks that square brackets `[]` are a sane idea for this. Redefining standards is their favorite pastime.

Comment: @joop The default behaviour is case *folding* as described here. It feels like it's case insensitive if all your identifiers are lower-case, because that's what other cases get folded to, but they are *specifically* referencing a lower-case identifier, not matching in a case-insensitive manner.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Apparently, [SQL Server 2012 also allows double-quotes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx), so it seems with the right settings you can actually follow this particular bit of standard in all the major DBMSes. :) (The point stands, though, that people don't, and MySQL users tend to be very used to their backticks.)

Comment: Ok, case-folding it is. You win.